# Acitvate a given window in a multi-window application with JXA

Tags: javascript-automation

Suppose I have two open TextEdit files, and consequently two windows.
How can I switch/activate windows programmatically with JXA?

At the moment I have this:

```
var text = Application("textEdit")
text.activate()
var file1_path = Path("/Users/..../text1.rtf")
var file2_path = Path("/Users/..../text2.rtf")

var doc1 = text.open(file1_path)
var doc2 = text.open(file2_path)

console.log("text1",text.windows["text1.rtf"].index()) //prints 2
console.log("text2",text.windows["text2.rtf"].index()) //prints 1

//the next row brings text1 window to front but doesn't activate it, 
//as a matter of fact the 3 buttons upper/left (close,minimize, full screen) are grey
text.windows["text1.rtf"].index = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a go, which appears to work on High Sierra:

```
TextEdit=Application('TextEdit');
Sys=Application('System Events');

TextEdit.activate()

/* open files, etc. */

Sys.processes["TextEdit"].windows[1].actions['AXRaise'].perform();
```

And you can, of course, replace the index `1` with the name of the window, such as `"text1.rtf"`.

Comment: Wonderful, I am very happy. Could you give me an extra bonus and tell me how could I get to it alone by reading docs and dictionary library? Many thanks